# Apple LLVM 5.1 error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

When i try to open an old project on Xcode Version 5.1.1, proprecompiler gives the following error

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fobjc' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

by the way some classes are compiled with `-fobjc -arc` flag.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I think Auto Reference Counting might have been enabled for few classes which you said some classes are percompiled with -fobjc -arc flag

Comment: use -fno-objc-arc to disable or -fobjc-arc to enable flags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the wrong flag. You should be using `-fobjc-arc`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your compiler flag again , its seems like you are using `-fobjc` instead of `-fobjc-arc` .
Use

- Enable ARC -> -fobjc-arc
- Disable ARC -> -fno-objc-arc